# Can you explain how this code works for me?

Tags: c

I'm kind of new to using for arrays so I'll try my best to comment which parts of this code I know and then I hope you can help me explain and clarify the rest of them. The goal is to get 10 elements (numbers) then sort them in order (biggest to smallest and vice versa)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input();
void sort();

int array[10];

int main()

{
  char ans='y';
  while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')  /// Run the program while 'y' is entered
{

input(); // run the input function
sort(); // run the sort function

printf("\n Run Program Again?"); // ask user for input (char ans)
scanf("%s",&ans);

}
} 

void input()
{
  int x;

  for (x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
{ //This is where I get confused. If my int x is =0, less than 10, I don't know what "++ means
    printf("\nInput: ");  //ask for input
    scanf("%d", &array[x]); //get the input typed in and place in array x
  }
}

void sort()

{
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
int biggerNum = 0;
int smallerNum = 0;  //set values for integers



for (z = 10; z > 0; z--) {  // can someone explain this part?
    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        if (array[z] < array[x])
            continue;
        else {
            biggerNum = array[z];
            smallerNum= array[x];
            array[z] = smallerNum;
            array[x] = biggerNum;
            printf("\n%d\t%d",array[z],array[x]);
         }
     }
   }

     printf("\nDescending order:");  

     for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)  // this is the algorithm for going down
         printf("\n %d",array[x]);

     printf("\nAscending Order:"); // same for going up
     for (x = 10; x > 0; x--)
         printf("\n %d",array[x]);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm describing. I think it will be helpful for you.

1st part:

```
    char ans='y';
    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')  /// Run the program while 'y' is entered
    {

        input(); // run the input function
        sort(); // run the sort function

        printf("\n Run Program Again?"); // ask user for input (char ans)
        scanf("%s",&ans);

    }
```

Firstly, You initialize `ans` (it's a character data type) by `'y'`. So, it will enter the `while` loop. Then by `input()` function you are taking 10 numbers. And then by `sort()` function you are sorting those 10 numbers from biggest to lowest and vise versa. And then you take the input `ans` again. If you(user) take again `'y'` or `'Y'` then it will be continue. Otherwise `while` loop will be break and program will terminate.

2nd Part:

```
void input()
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        //This is where I get confused. If my int x is =0, less than 10, I dont
       //know what "++ means
        printf("\nInput: ");  //ask for input
        scanf("%d", &array[x]); //get the input typed in and place in array x
    }
}
```

This code actually for taking 10 numbers. Here '`x++`' means increment of `x`. That means `x=x+1`. You are storing those 10 numbers in array by `scanf`.

3rd Part:

```
void sort()
{
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int biggerNum = 0;
        int smallerNum = 0;  //set values for integers

        for (z = 10; z > 0; z--)    // can someone explain this part?
        {
            for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
            {
                if (array[z] < array[x])
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    biggerNum = array[z];
                    smallerNum= array[x];
                    array[z] = smallerNum;
                    array[x] = biggerNum;
                    printf("\n%d\t%d",array[z],array[x]);
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\nDescending order:");

        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)  // this is the algorithm for going down
            printf("\n %d",array[x]);

        printf("\nAscending Order:"); // same for going up
        for (x = 10; x > 0; x--)
            printf("\n %d",array[x]);
    }
```

It's the sorting of 10 numbers. Actually it's called [bubble sort](http://www.programiz.com/algorithm/bubble-sort).